# Statistics of visits on M.SE

Tags: support, statistics

As it is possible to see the last time when you or others visited M.SE, I wonder if one can see a statistics of visits of your own or of a specific user for a period of time (last year, let's say).

Answer (score 8):

This is more of a supplement to [quid's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24877).

Regular users can only see the visits information for their own account. Where in [your own profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) you might see

[image: my profile with visits data]

looking at [another user's profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arjafi?tab=profile) will show

[image: another's profile without visits data]

On the other hand site moderators (and SE employees) can see any user's complete visit information, including the little calendar showing exact (UTC) dates visited.

Answer (score 5):

A partial answer:

For your own account this data is available in detail and nicely presented: [go to your user profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile), then  clicking on "visited {number} days, {othernumber} consecutive" will give you a calendar marking each and every day you visited.

Comment: I will add that this meta.SE also has a picture illustrating this: [How can I see which days I visited site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128605/how-can-i-see-which-days-i-visited-site)